# Grails 3 Quartz plugin: Job doesn't start

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin, grails-3.1

I am trying to do a simple background job in Grails. I just want stuff to happen every 30 seconds or so.

I am using Grails 3.1.3

I've added Quartz to my dependencies:
compile "org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.1"

Then I've run a compile and restarted the grails CLI. Now I created a Job via create-job. It looks like this:

```
package htwp

class UserSyncJob {
    static triggers = {
      simple repeatInterval: 5000l // execute job once in 5 seconds
    }

    def execute() {
        println ("?")
        log.error("??!")
        throw new Error("JOB WHERE ARE YOU");
    }
}
```

Nothing happens when I start the server via run-app. Nothing printed, no errors either. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try the latest 2.0.8 version? https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/releases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked issues of quartz plugin for Grails project and found [this issue](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/issues/48) and [this issue](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/issues/39).

Just upgrade as I said earlier in comment to [the newest realese](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/releases) of plugin.

Comment: quartz 2.0.13 is not starting in grails 3.3.10